# ODI KM substitution phase code it's getting wrong after submit

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I'm writing KM's in ODI 12.2.1. I'm having the next problem:
after I'm finish writing a code in a task and press "OK" some lines of the code are changed (wrong):
example of correct code:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE <?=tempTblNmDt?>
SELECT
<%=odiRef.getAllTargetColList("", "cast([COL_NAME] as [DEST_CRE_DT]) as [COL_NAME]", ",\n\t", "","") %>
FROM
(
SELECT
<%=odiRef.getColList("", "<? if ( (\u0022[DEST_CRE_DT]\u0022==\u0022TIMESTAMP\u0022) && (\u0022[DATA_FORMAT]\u0022!=\u0022N/A\u0022) ) {?> from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( [EXPRESSION], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS [COL_NAME]  <? } else { ?> cast([EXPRESSION] as [DEST_CRE_DT]) as [COL_NAME] <? }?>", ",\n\t", "","(INS and UPD)") %>
--TECHNICAL COLUMNS
,<?=vT_DL_CTI?> as T_DL_CTI
,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as T_DL_INS_DT
,'<?=partDate?>' T_DL_COB_DT
FROM <?=tempTblNmStr?> <$=tableAlias$>
) SUBSELECT
```

After pressing Apply>OK:

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLE <?=tempTblNmDt?>
SELECT
<%=odiRef.getAllTargetColList("", "cast([COL_NAME] as [DEST_CRE_DT]) as [COL_NAME]", ",\n\t", "","") %>
FROM
(
SELECT
<%=odiRef.getColList("", "<? if ( (\u0022[DEST_CRE_DT]\u0022==\u0022TIMESTAMP\u0022) && (\u0022[DATA_FORMAT]\u0022!=\u0022N/A\u0022) ) {?> from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( [EXPRESSION], 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS [COL_NAME]  <? } else { ?> cast([EXPRESSION] as [DEST_CRE_DT]) as [COL_NAME] <? }?>", ",\n\t", "","(INS and UPD)") %>
--TECHNICAL COLUMNS
,<?=vT_DL_CTI?> as T_DL_CTI
,from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) as T_DL_INS_DT
,'<?=partDate?>' T_DL_COB_DT
FROM <?=tempTblNmStr?> <$=tableAlias$>T
) SUBSELECT
```

Example 2:
Before:

```
<$ if (KM_ALL_DELIVERY_TYPE.equals("INTRA_DAY_DELTA")) 
{
$>
<@
  intraDayPartitionLocation = "#location";
@>
<$
}
$>
```

After:

```
<$ if (KM_ALL_DELIVERY_TYPE.equals("INTRA_DAY_DELTA")) 
{
$>
<@
  intraDayPartitionLocation = "#location";
@>
<
}
$>
```

Example 3
Before:

```
<$ if (KM_ALL_DELIVERY_TYPE.equals("INTRA_DAY_DELTA")) 
{
$>
    SELECT
      ifnull(substring(location,instr(location,'datalake')),'N/A') location
    FROM
      hive.DBS
    LEFT JOIN hive.TBLS
    ON
      (
        DBS.DB_ID       = TBLS.DB_ID
      AND upper(TBLS.tbl_name) = '<$=tableShortNm$>_RAW'
      )
    LEFT JOIN hive.PARTITIONS
    ON
      (
        TBLS.TBL_ID = PARTITIONS.TBL_ID
      AND PARTITIONS.PART_NAME LIKE '%<$=partDate$>%'
      )
    LEFT JOIN hive.SDS
    ON
      (
        PARTITIONS.SD_ID = SDS.SD_ID
      )
    WHERE
      upper(DBS.name)='<$=rawSchema$>'
<$
}
$>
```

After:

```
<$ if (KM_ALL_DELIVERY_TYPE.equals("INTRA_DAY_DELTA")) 
{
$>
    SELECT
      ifnull(substring(location,instr(location,'datalake')),'N/A') location
    FROM
      hive.DBS
    LEFT JOIN hive.TBLS
    ON
      (
        DBS.DB_ID       = TBLS.DB_ID
      AND upper(TBLS.tbl_name) = '<$=tableShortNm$>_RAW'
      )
    LEFT JOIN hive.PARTITIONS
    ON
      (
        TBLS.TBL_ID = PARTITIONS.TBL_ID
      AND PARTITIONS.PART_NAME LIKE '%<$=partDate$>%'
      )
    LEFT JOIN hive.SDS
    ON
      (
        PARTITIONS.SD_ID = SDS.SD_ID
      )
    WHERE
      upper(DBS.name>='<$=rawSchema$>'
<$
}
$>
```

This "broke code" is not always the same. Sometimes the substitution variables are broken. If need, I can provide more examples.

The workaround solution is to write your code in an external application (like notepad) and then to copy-paste the code in the section Command from the properties task (not in the task directly).

Does anyone know what is the cause of the problem?
It not happens on every task.

Comment: What exactly is broken "after pressing ok"? The only difference I see is that `<$=tableAlias$>T` has an additional `T`. Could you please provide another example?

Comment: Hi @Rajmondx. I putted two new examples. With "broken" I wanted to say that the code it's written bad .. in different ways. In the first example it's an additional T, in the second it's a missing "$" and in the third, replaces the last ")" with ">"...